# redirecting to multiple virtual subdomains using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to create subdomains via htaccess. The code below does exactly want I want

It takes http://domain.com and redirect it to http://www.domain.com

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.asp index.php
ErrorDocument 401 http://www.domain.com
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.domain.com
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.domain.com
ErrorDocument 507 http://www.domain.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
AddType text/html .html .htm .asp
```

This is the part I am not to sure of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com/nl$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://nl.domain.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

How can I create virtual subdomains so that if someone goes to http://nl.domain.com it would stay on http://nl.domain.com if someone types http://www.nl.domain.com it would take out the http://www.nl.domain.com and make it http://nl.domain.com also the directory structure for the subdomain would be http://www.domain.com/nl (This is where the actual files will be sitting).

so if someone goes to http://www.domain.com/nl it should also redirect to http://nl.domain.com.

Thanks in advance for any advice and pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

# The ordering of the following rules is somewhat important

#
# External redirects with HTTP "301 - Moved Permanently" for subdomains
# 

# Redirect www.nl.example.com to nl.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.nl\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://nl.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

# Instead I could do this to redirect any prefix before nl to nl.example.com
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+?\.nl\.example\.com$
# RewriteRule ^(.*) http://nl.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

# Redirect www.foo.example.com to foo.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.foo\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://foo.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

# Instead I could do this to redirect any prefix before foo to foo.example.com
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+?\.foo\.example\.com$
# RewriteRule ^(.*) http://foo.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

# Rewrite any remaining subdomains to example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^nl\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^foo\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

# Assuming from this point forward we have either
# example.com, nl.example.com, or foo.example.com as the HTTP_HOST

# Redirect example.com/nl to nl.example.com
# (Note that ONLY example.com/nl is caught here.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^nl(/(.*))? http://nl.example.com/$2 [QSA,L,R=301]

# Redirect example.com/foo to foo.example.com
# (Note that ONLY example.com/foo is caught here.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^foo(/(.*))? http://foo.example.com/$2 [QSA,L,R=301]

#
# Internal rewrites for directory structuring
#

# Internal rewrite for the nl subdomain
#  - Match the subdomain exactly
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nl\.example\.com$
#  - Check to see if the rewrite already happened (prevent
#    infinite loop of internal rewrites)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/nl(/.*|$)
#  - Rewrite the URL to the subdirectory
RewriteRule ^(.*) /nl/$1 [L]

# Internal rewrite for the foo subdomain
#  - Match the subdomain exactly
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.example\.com$
#  - Check to see if the rewrite already happened (prevent
#    infinite loop of internal rewrites)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo(/.*|$)
#  - Rewrite the URL to the subdirectory
RewriteRule ^(.*) /foo/$1 [L]
```

<del>I haven't tested the above on a server, but</del> I tested it on my local server, it should be close to what you need if I understood you correctly.

I'm sure you've seen the [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). In addition to that, the [Rewrite Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html) and the [Advanced Rewrite Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewrite_guide_advanced.html) have helpful practical examples.

Comment: Hi Robert thank you very much for the effort in providing me with a solution to the problem. I will test it sometime later today and will let you know if it worked!